# Run 3 scripts in single folder

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script that will run 3 scripts, these 3 scripts i need to put it into a folder called date and time which will take from the system.

For example

1. i have a 3 scripts called A.sh, B.sh, C.sh these three scripts are running from a single script.
2. each script has a different output.
3. These three outputs should be in a single directory called date_and_time
4. I will give you a small picture how the out put should be http://photouploads.com/images/example.png

Can any one suggest me how to solve this problem

Comment: To clarify something: your output directory should be called "date_and_time" literally, or something along the lines of "2012-06-22-15:48:23" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use smth like this: (contents of your running script, say `run3.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash
A.sh > date_and_time/A.output &
B.sh > date_and_time/B.output &
C.sh > date_and_time/C.output &
```

Answer (score 0):

you may also use a sub shell like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
DIRNAME=$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
( $DIRNAME/A.sh ; $DIRNAME/B.sh ; $DIRNAME/C.sh ) > $DIRNAME/Text.txt
```

Comment: This does not actually solve the problem sketched in the graph but combines the output of the scripts into one file. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to have timestamped output directories, this might be a good starting point:

```
#!/bin/sh

TIMESTAMP=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M:%S"`

OUTPUT="$TIMESTAMP.d"

mkdir -p "$OUTPUT"

A.sh > "$OUTPUT/A.out"
B.sh > "$OUTPUT/B.out"
C.sh > "$OUTPUT/C.out"

echo "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." > "$OUTPUT"/Text.txt

# Let our users know where to find the output...
echo "Output directory: $OUTPUT"
```

Basically, this script uses the [`date`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command to get the current date and time in a more standardized format and then creates an output directory with the same name.

Caveat: If you run this script twice within the same computer clock second, the output of the second run will overwrite the first one. I'll leave handling this particular corner case as an exercise for the reader...